# Prove that there exists some real number θ satisfying 0 < θ < 1 for which f '''(θ) = 0

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let f: D → R be a 3-times differentiable function defined over an open interval D,
where 0 ∈ D and 1 ∈ D. Suppose that f(0) = f '(0) = 0 and f(1) = f '(1) = 0.

Prove that there exists some real number θ satisfying 0 < θ < 1 for which f '''(θ) = 0

This is my attempt: as f is 3 times differentiable this implies that f '(x) and f ''(x) are continuous on [0,1]

Using Rolle's Theorem and the fact that f(0)=f(1), there exist some t$_1$ such that 0 < t$_1$ < 1

and f '(t$_1$)=0

Using Rolle's again as f '(0) = f '(t$_1$) there exist some t$_2$ such that 0 < t$_2$ < 1 and f ''(t$_2$) = 0

I cant figure out how to find t$_3$ such that f '''(t$_3$)=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $f'(t_1) = f'(1)$ also and now $t_1$ separates the two points whose second derivative is zero.

Answer (score 2):

$f(0)=f(1)=0$, there  exists $x_1\in (0,1)$ such that $f'(x_1)=0$,

$f'(0)=f'(x_1)=f'(1)=0$, there exists $x_2\in (0,x_1), x_3\in (x_1,1), f"(x_2)=f"(x_3)=0$, so there exists $x_4\in (x_2,x_3)$ such that $f"'(x_4)=0$.

Comment: $x_2\in(0,x_ {\color{red}1})$.